# Call array value outside php class and function

Tags: arrays, function, class

I'm trying to call an array value outside a php class and function but don't really know how to do this correctly so I was hoping if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
  Class hello {
     public function world(){
         $myArray = array(
           'key' => 'This is the value'.
           'key1' => 'This is the value of key 1.'
         );
     }      
  }
```

Now I would like to echo the value of key on another page, but don't know how.
I know how to call the function with $hello = new hello; $hello->world(); but would like to retreive the values seperatly.